# Embedding a custom Google Maps in Google Sites

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I made a custom google map that I would like to embed on a Google Site. I tested the code in a Dynamic Content Writer and it worked fine. I tried to load it into the HTML box and got the following message: 
"9+9 - 58: failed to load external url js?sensor=false".

I read that I could try converting the code in a Google Gadget,but that produced this error message:

The gadget you added is not valid

Unsupported feature: org.apache.shindig.common.xml.XmlException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference. At: (1,927)

My code is available here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1295106d8bb997a046e2500feb584a6f

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252810/error-when-adding-html-to-google-site-google-maps-api

Comment: Yes. My specific problem is that the API key is not working.

Comment: Nvm. Resolved by refreshing the Google Maps API key. Not sure what that worked, but meh.